# Check if all keywords matched at least one column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write an SQL query that will search to check if ALL keywords are present over multiple columns. The keywords may contain wildcard characters such as '%' to represent any string.

E.g.

```
first_name  | last_name | age   | height    | mother's name
-------------------------------------------------------
 mary       | jones     | 19    | 170       | sally jane     
 john       | doe       | 43    | 165       | sarah connor
 john       | connor    | 17    | 173       | sarah connor
 joe        | bloe      | 32    | 173       | sarah connor
 john       | connor    | 32    | 165       | sarah connor
```

If I search for 'jo% %connor%', I need to find all rows where at least one column contains 'jo%' and at least one column contains '%connor%' and I need to make sure that all of the keywords have matched at least one column.

I cannot use full text search on the table. And I don't think I can just concatenate all the columns and check if it contains all of the words because of the wild cards in the search terms which may state that the beginning of the word must start with jo.

Is there a good way to do this kind of search in SQL Server 2012 without altering the table properties etc?

Comment: what happens if first_name is 'mary' and last_name is 'joconnor'? is it a match? it validates 'jo%' and '%connor%' but it is the same column.

Comment: no. The spaces will delimit the words

Comment: does it have to be a wild card search? if not you can just do an OR if you have a finite number of columns

Comment: `@searchString like col1+col2+col3+Col4+Col5 OR @searchString like Col2+Col1+Col3+Col4+Col5 OR @searchString like Col3+Col1+Col2+Col4+Col5 OR ...` just permut one column at the bigining each time

Comment: But how do I know all of the keywords were found? And yes, it must be able to do a wildcard search

Comment: there is actually a similar case that i am looking for with an answer using PIVOT but can't seem to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option where you don't have to detail all the fields to search, and it will return only the records where ALL where hit, **while respecting the individual search patterns**

Now, I used my Parse Function, but can easily be converted to an in-line query.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([first_name] varchar(50),[last_name] varchar(50),[age] int,[height] int,[mother_name] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 ('mary','jones',19,170,'sally jane')
,('john','doe',43,165,'sarah connor')
,('john','connor',17,173,'sarah connor')
,('joe','bloe',32,173,'sarah connor')
,('john','connor',32,165,'sarah connor')


Declare @Search varchar(max) = 'jo% %connor%'

;with cte as (
                Select *,MaxHit=max(RetSeq) over () From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@Search,' ')
             )
Select A.* 
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select XMLData=convert(xml,(Select A.* For XML RAW))) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Hits=count(*)
                  From (
                        Select Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                         From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                        ) C1
                 Join cte C2 on patindex(C2.RetVal,Value)>0
                 Having count(Distinct C2.RetSeq)>=max(C2.MaxHit)
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
first_name  last_name   age height  mother_name
john        doe         43  165     sarah connor
john        connor      17  173     sarah connor
joe         bloe        32  173     sarah connor
john        connor      32  165     sarah connor
```

**The Parse Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

> **EDIT - Option without XML - (much more perforant than XML)**

```
Declare @Search varchar(max) = 'jo% %connor%'

;with cte as (
                Select *,MaxHit=max(RetSeq) over () From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@Search,' ')
             )
Select A.*,C.*
 From #Temp A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Hits=count(Distinct C2.RetSeq)
                  From ( values (A.[first_name])
                               ,(A.[last_name])
                               ,(concat('',A.[age]))
                               ,(concat('',A.[height]))
                               ,(A.[mother_name])
                        ) C1 (Value)
                 Join cte C2 on patindex(C2.RetVal,Value)>0
                 Having count(Distinct C2.RetSeq)>=max(C2.MaxHit)
             ) C
```

**Note:** I put the delimiter back to [SPACE], but this would preclude searches like '%sarah connor%'.   Personally, I prefer a token like PIPE, but that is a choice.   Further more you can search dates, or and/or numerics.

Comment: I think this works, but it is very slow. It takes 20 seconds to complete for 6500 records. I will accept the answer if no one can give me a better performing query.

Comment: I have to go through the query to understand exactly what is going on as it is more complex than what I am used to. But is it necessary to convert to XML? I believe this might be slowing things down.

Comment: @Asagohan The XML portion is certainly not optimized.  It simply DYNAMICALLY unpivots your data (without having to specify all the field names and avoids datatype conficts).  UNPIVOT would most certainly be more performant,  That said, I can't imagine where you are getting 20 seconds.   Just for fun I expanded your data to 20,000 rows and got results in 1.8 seconds (on my laptop).

Comment: @Asagohan The edit option returns the results in 0.187 seconds

Comment: @Asagohan You may also notice that I used concat() vs cast() or convert() for the numerics.   From my experience, I've found this to be faster, but I have not seen any definitive bechmarks on this

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help. I may have got 20 seconds previously because my actual data is more complicated than in my example. Now it is very quick.

Comment: @Asagohan Happy it helped.   I use the XML approach in a dynamic procedure where I pass a table, view, or even a select.   I'm a little ashamed that you witnessed such horrible performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial, but you could split the search string (assuming not pattern has spaces).  Then, assuming you have a unique id for each row:

```
with s(pattern) as (
      select *
      from dbo.split(@str, ' ')
     )
select t.*
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from s
      where (first_name + last_name + cast(age as varchar(255)) + '|' + cast(height as varchar(255)) + '|' + mothername) like concat('%', s.pattern, '%')
     ) s
where s.cnt = (select count(*) from s);
```

Comment: I am not sure what the "where" portion is doing. Is it supposed to be concatenating first_name, etc.? It doesn't work in SQL server in the form that it is in